# rest implicitly has type any because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

So i'm trying to create a private route using react router 4 and Typescript. Here is my code:

```
type PrivateRouteProps<T> = T & { component: any, authRequired: boolean };

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authRequired, ...rest }: PrivateRouteProps<typeof rest>) {
 return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => authRequired === true
            ? <Layout><Component {...props} /></Layout>
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/home', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
    />
 );
}
```

I'm having an issue with the ...rest arg in the PrivateRoute function, it is giving the error:

> 'rest' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

I've looked at the typescript docs for object destructuring, but I can't seem to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do `typeof rest` because it doesn't know what type `rest` is.